# Android Studio add padding to the icon ic_launcher.png

Tags: android, icons, android-studio, padding

[image]

[image]

I'm beginner android developer. I can't figure out why AS automatically adds padding to my png file. I added the png file through res-New-Image Asset- add my png file for android app icon. 
The File doesn't have padding.

Answer (score 2):

Try clicking this, I hope this will help ;)[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found two solutions to get around the extra padding that Android Studio adds when creating icons:

1. Resize images using a [Windows] batch file.  This is the one I use because it's the easiest for me (on Windows):

   a. Create a ResizeImage.exe using the simple code from http://www.ianmcintyre.com/2014/06/c-resize-image-fit-image.html

   b. Save the following ResizeAndroidLauncherImage.bat file in the same directory as ResizeImage.exe.  This copies your original image to the various directories and resizes them:

   ```
   @echo off
   setlocal

   set subdir=%2
   set iconsize=512
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher-web.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher-web.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-xxxhdpi
   set iconsize=192
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-xxhdpi
   set iconsize=144
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-xhdpi
   set iconsize=96
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-hdpi
   set iconsize=72
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   set subdir=%2\res\mipmap-mdpi
   set iconsize=48
   if not exist "%subdir%" mkdir "%subdir%"
   copy /Y %1 %subdir%\ic_launcher.png
   %~dp0ResizeImage.exe %subdir%\ic_launcher.png %iconsize% %iconsize%

   endlocal
   ```

   c. Execute the batch file every time you update your icon:

   ```
   ResizeAndroidLauncherImage.bat [YourIcon.png] [YourAndreoidSRCDir]
   ```
2. Use the Android Asset Studio (https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html).  You'll have to modify the source to remove the extra padding.  See https://github.com/romannurik/AndroidAssetStudio/issues/73 for a discussion on how to do that. I tried this and used "none":

   ```
   const TARGET_RECTS_BY_SHAPE = { none: { x: 0, y: 0, w: 46, h: 46 }, circle: { x: 2, y: 2, w: 44, h: 44 }, square: { x: 5, y: 5, w: 38, h: 38 }, vrect: { x: 8, y: 2, w: 32, h: 44 }, hrect: { x: 2, y: 8, w: 44, h: 32 }, };
   ```

If I had Photoshop on my development machine, I would also try:

3. Record and play back a batch script in Photoshop.  [Note that I did not try this]